# The same Web API Code works on Windows 10 but not on Linux Debian Buster

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, api-design

In the screenshot below, i have my Web API running with .NET5.0 on Windows 10 (left) and the same Web API running with .NET(core?)5.0 on Linux Debian Buster (right) (WSL2).

[image: Pìcture showing API map on Windows (left) and on Linux (right)]

As you can see, on Windows it maps the controllers correctly, but not on Linux. I'm showing the Swagger page to be more explicit, but if I access the routes manually, the behaviour is the same.

Does anyone know what could be and how to solve this problem? I have to make it work on Linux because my deployment target is a debian based server.

Below are some code that may be useful (Startup.cs and a Controller declaration)

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<Core.Contexts.ComiesContext>(o => {o.UseSqlServer("name=LocalComiesDBConn"); o.ConfigureWarnings(p => p. Ignore(30000));});
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "comies_services", Version = "v1" }));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Core.Contexts.ComiesContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var signingConfigurations = new Structures.ModelsConfigurations.SigningConfigurations(Configuration["TokenConfigurations:securityKey"]);
        services.AddSingleton(signingConfigurations);

        var tokenConfigurations = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
        new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<AuthenticationConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("TokenConfigurations")).Configure(tokenConfigurations);
        services.AddSingleton(tokenConfigurations);

        services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
        {
            authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
        {
            var paramsValidation = jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters;

            paramsValidation.IssuerSigningKey = signingConfigurations.Key;
            paramsValidation.ValidAudience = tokenConfigurations.Audience;
            paramsValidation.ValidIssuer = tokenConfigurations.Issuer;

            paramsValidation.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;

            paramsValidation.ValidateLifetime = true;

            paramsValidation.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
        });

        // Ativa o uso do token como forma de autorizar o acesso
        // a recursos deste projeto
        services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            
            auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        });


        services.AddScoped<AuthenticatedOperator>();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationService>();
        services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddTransient<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "comies_services v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

AuthController.cs

```
[Route("api/v1/auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ComiesContext _context;

    private readonly AuthenticationService _authenticationService;

    public AuthenticationController(ComiesContext context, AuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _context = context; _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }


    // GET: api/<AuthenticationController>
    [HttpGet("register/template")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Store>> Get()
    {
        ///hidden implementation, but trust me, this endpoint is working (when it's mapped)
    }
```

Comment: I have same behaviour with one project. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample project with the controller you posted, but I cannot reproduce the behavior. It is working, no problem there.

Try check the Swagger version, it should be above 5.6.3

```
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
```

Comment: It is. The problem is not Swagger actually, I just showed it for y'all to see how the controllers are (or are not) mapped. But if I navigate to the route itself, it returns 404 as well, to all of em

Comment: May be it is connected with https? Try to setup https like here https://thegreenerman.medium.com/set-up-https-on-local-with-net-core-and-docker-7a41f030fc76

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and managed to find a solution that worked for me (although it may not be applicable to everyone). In my case, I had a folder named "API" with mixed casing (some letters in uppercase and some in lowercase), along with another folder named "Api" in all lowercase. Due to the case-insensitive nature of Windows, the folders were merged, and any .cs files within them were discovered. However, when I tried the same on Linux, the files were not detected. The root cause of this problem lies in the fact that Git for Windows, as well as the Windows operating system itself, are not case-sensitive, whereas Linux is. To resolve this issue, I recommend carefully examining the folder names and ensuring that the casing is consistent.